# Extracting rows from SQL query given a certain value

Tags: sql, sqlite, extract, rows

The column `c` is in ascending order as you can see below.

Let's say I have a value `x = 25`; I want to extract the rows between which 25 lies corresponding to the `c` column. Clearly 25 lies between rows 2 and 3.

How can I extract rows 2 and 3 from a SQL query?

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 5 |
| 700 | 2000 | 20 |
| 600 | 110 | 100 |

Comment: What if c=25? What if there are two rows with c=25?

Comment: Yes, 'c' can be 25 but there cannot be two rows with c = 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all the values less or equal to 25. Then order them by c and take the first.

Do it again for c greater than 25.

You can do two queries and `union` them.

```
select *
from table
where c <= 25
order by c desc
limit 1

union

select *
from table
where c > 25
order by c asc
limit 1
```

Comment: There cannot be multiple ows with c = 25 but can be a singl row with c =25

Comment: What if I want that If c = 25 is detected then I do not want anything else, I just want the row corresponding to  c = 25

Comment: @ayush_maheshwari Off the top of my head, I'm not sure. Since there's just two rows, I'd filter it in the application logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use it.

```
WITH temp as (SELECT a, b, c
              , min( CASE WHEN 25 < c THEN c ELSE NULL END ) OVER ( ORDER BY c )      AS col1
              , max( CASE WHEN 25 < c THEN NULL ELSE c END ) OVER ( ORDER BY c DESC ) AS col2
         FROM data
         ORDER BY c)
SELECT a,b,c
FROM temp t
WHERE t.col1 = t.c
   OR t.col2 = t.c
```

Also, if you don't want to pass 25 as parameter you can add it to table/view as column

[test it](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cVeqoGAMNCWD4KaP2keLVR/4)

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM tablename t2
            WHERE t2.c <> t1.c
              AND (t2.c BETWEEN t1.c AND ? OR t2.c BETWEEN ? AND t1.c)
          );
```

Replace `?` with the value that you want.

Results for `? = 25`:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 700 | 2000 | 20 |
| 600 | 110 | 100 |

Results for `? = 20`:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 700 | 2000 | 20 |

Results for `? = 4`:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 5 |

Results for `? = 110`:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 600 | 110 | 100 |

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sTm1jmmSZfzQnDFngpSq8i/0).